# Is it possible to insert captions into a `numcases` structure?

Tags: equations, captions, cases

I have a system of equations determined with `numcases` like so:

```
\begin{numcases}{}
   \partial_t u_1 = \nabla \cdot D(u_1) \nabla u_1 + \mu_1 f(c, k_1) u_1 - \delta_1 u_1 \label{sender:eq} \\
   \partial_t u_2 = \nabla \cdot D(u_2) \nabla u_2 + \mu_2 f(c,k_2)u_2 - \delta_2 u_2 \label{receiver:eq}
\end{numcases}
```

But is there a way to insert a descriptive caption, like for a table, into this structure?

Comment: Should it also be called "table" or something different? Should it float or stay where it is used in the code?

Comment: @leandriis It doesn't have to be a table, it's just a system of equations, and it doesn't need to float. It is basically static text.

Comment: What label should have this caption?

Comment: @Zarko The system itself should have this caption, not a particular equation or label.

Comment: Captions have counters and support \listof...  You can create a new caption/float type using the newfloat package.  May I instead suggest using the subequations environment, and possibly \text{...}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear,Your should provide an sketch, haw you imagine caption of an equation system. So, I guessing, that caption can be something like this:

[image]

simplest code for this is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]

\captionof*{figure}{this is caption of equation system}
\begin{numcases}{}
   \partial_t u_1 = \nabla \cdot D(u_1) \nabla u_1 + \mu_1 f(c, k_1) u_1 - \delta_1 u_1 \label{sender:eq} \\
   \partial_t u_2 = \nabla \cdot D(u_2) \nabla u_2 + \mu_2 f(c,k_2)u_2 - \delta_2 u_2 \label{receiver:eq}
\end{numcases}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

This approach has significantly flaw: caption is not tied with equation system. That to be, both (caption and equations) should be in some environment, but this can badly effected document formatting.

It might be, that you like to have some comment inline with equations? Let us know!

Comment: @sequence, any news?